# having по двум вхожденям

Tags: mysql

Есть таблица

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно найти все id, которые содержат значения в поле digits '15' и '16' одновременно. Т.е. в данном случае - только id = 1.

Пробую

```
SELECT id from table group by digits having count(digits=15)>=1 and count(digits=16)>=1;
```

результат выводит неверный.

Comment: `where digits in(15, 16) group by id having count(1) = 2`

Comment: На всякий случае лучше `HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT digits) = 2`. Вдруг структура допускает дубликаты?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`count(digits=15)` даст значение при любом значении `digits`, кроме NULL - и неважно, какое это будет значение, 1 или 0, но это значение. Так что это эквивалентно простому `count(digits)`.

А вот `count(CASE WHEN digits=15 then 1 END)` только для 15 даст значение (причём неважно, что написать вместо единицы, лишь бы не NULL). Если значение `digits` не 15 (в т.ч. NULL) - CASE даст NULL, который не будет посчитан. И запрос даст верные данные.